# Automatic broker in-sync-replicate partition re-assignment

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using Kafka 2.6.

Kafka assigns broker ids sequentially. When I stop and start an instance of Kafka a new ID is assigned. I don't have an easy way to manually assign broker ids because I am using a cloud provider.

The following property will automatically assign a new leader if the leader is restarted: `auto.leader.rebalance.enable`.

However, if a in-sync-replica is restarted, its not automatically replaced.

How can I have Kafka automatically assign a new in-sync-replica when one is lost?